# yii2. REST API нужно ли использовать rbac yii2, или создать свой?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть REST API с кучей функционала , но система RBAC мне нужна только на системы груп. В групах может быть: owner, administrator, moderator.

Дело в том, что система rbac должна быть только для груп и не более.
Для всего остального мне не нужно проверять роль пользователя.

Что лучше использовать для этого? Дефолтный RBAC от yii2 или писать свой?

Я читал(где то в интернете) что RBAC от yii2 лучше не использовать для таких случаев, но хотел бы убедиться как лучше реализовать.

Если писать свой то где и на каком уровне делать проверку на роль?

Answer (score 0):

Таких вопросов не должно возникать. Если есть готовый функционал, надо его использовать. Функционал избыточен? Так это сейчас он избыточен, через год уже (возможно) придется использовать весь функционал. А через три года его может не хватать.

Вопрос подобен этому: Нам надо лететь в Питер, но самолеты летают в разные города и страны, при этом есть еще грузовые и военные, поэтому склепаем свои крылья. Пол дороги точно пролетим, а там будет видно.

И пример из жизни. Однажды мне понадобилось вставить 4 двери. При покупке я решил сэкономить и купить вместо собранных коробок и врезанных замков все отдельно и в разобранном виде. Экономия была порядка 5000, может чуть больше. В итоге я провозился целых семь дней, вместо двух дней. Эти 5 дней мне слишком дорого обошлись.

В айтишке все точно также, только стоимость одного дня дороже ))